# De lista a data frame

Tags: r

Supongamos que tengo 3 ficheros de texto txt, quiero cargar los 3 ficheros,
sacar cierta información (siempre se encuentran en la misma fila) y meterla en un df.

Cargo los datos.

```
nombre_ficheros <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")  


lista_datos <- lapply(nombre_ficheros, read.csv,
               fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-1",
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               sep="\n")
```

Los datos siempre están en la fila 2,4,6,8,19 y 21.

```
lista[[1]][2,]-> fecha
lista[[1]][4,]-> nombre
lista[[1]][6,]-> departamento
lista[[1]][8,]-> supervisor
lista[[1]][19,]-> respuesta1
lista[[1]][21,]-> respuesta2
```

Hago un df con ellos

```
datos <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(fecha,nombre,
        departamento,supervisor,respuesta1,respuesta2))
```

Esto sacaría la informacion del primer txt, ¿cómo hago para sacarlo de los tres?
Tendría que hacer un bucle e ir añadiendo los datos al df.

El df final seria algo como esto:

```
Nombre_fichero      fecha       nombre   departamento......
txt1              1/2/2020       pepe1     dpt1
txt2              1/3/2020       pepe2    dpt2
txt3              1/4/2021       pepe3    dpt3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que podrías hacer algo así:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lista_datos, function(x) x[c(2,4,6,8,19,21),]))
```

---

Básicamente, con `lapply()`  sobre la lista de los datos, donde cada elemento tiene la información de cada archivo, aplicamos una extracción de los datos de interés `function(x) x[c(2,4,6,8,19,21),]` que suponemos están siempre en las mismas filas, esto genera matrices de iguales dimensiones que luego con `do.call()` unimos mediante `rbind()`.

El resultado va a ser un matriz, si lo quieres como `data.frame`:

```
m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lista_datos, function(x) x[c(1,2),]))
as.data.frame(m)
```